# Web server on local machine, are there any gotchas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, webserver, xampp

If I use xampp or some other software to set up a local "webserver" on my PC since I don't have hosting yet, should I expect some html, javascript, or php code that would work on the web not to work on the local webserver, or is it virtually an identical testing environment as an actual webserver?

Comment: Not really an SO question. But that is the point of xampp, wamp, etc. They should more or less function as real servers. Most devs I know do their developing locally.

Comment: Code that works on the web should work on a local server

Comment: There are some exceptions like mail, which often is a real pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code interacts with the host system (manipulating files and directories, running OS commands) or with other programs (like mailer), there are chances that things will break when you move from your windows machine to a real hosting (which will most probably be linux). Also, if you use any non-standard php modules, getting them running on windows could be troublesome.

Installing a virtual machine with linux and running web/db servers in their native environment might be a better option than xammp or similar tools. This config is more difficult to set up, but more convenient and flexible in the long run. Popular VM runners are VirtualBox, Parallels and VMWare - google them up.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running the same version of services that your hosting provides. This will help you: http://www.host-shopper.com/basic-web-hosting-options.html

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is the OS specific directory structure; I use a windows computer but LAMPP on a linux server, so I have to keep those differences in mind.

On my PC webroot is

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs
```

On my XAMMP linux box webroot is

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs
```

but on my apache linux boxes webroot is either

```
/var/www/
```

or

```
/var/www/html/
```

These settings typically reflect defaults, they can be changed in your server config, but that would be a big gotcha as far as trying to just dump some local code on a server, any absolute path references might just crash and burn.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue I can think of would be subdomains on localhost, but you should be all set for now.

BTW, once you get it setup, I recommend checking out GitHub so if you ever break your site you can revert back.